# Snowflake - snowsql PUT command upload very slow

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've been having issues with the PUT command using Snowflake's SnowSQL Client. My network's upload speed is 100 Mbps, but the PUT command takes almost a minute and a half for a ~30MB file. I have already gzipped the file, so the compression isn't taking this long. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

PUT command speed

[image: img]

Comment: Can you try to upload the same file through the Snowflake UI and see how long that takes?

Answer (score 0):

There is always encryption occurring on the local machine, so whether the file is compressed or not, the machine the PUT is running on will still affect the overall performance of the PUT.  If the machine is under-powered or busy, can affect the performance.  If you are watching the PUT happen, you can tell how long this is taking by viewing when the bytes transferred actually starts moving.

Comment: I'm using a machine with and i5 8th gen without anything else running on the computer. Even with encryption, I don't believe it should be taking over a minute for a 30MB file.

Comment: I'd look at performance monitor while it's running and see what is going on with CPU, Memory, and Network traffic.  It'd give you a good idea of where the time is being spent.

Comment: I have been watching it and don't see anything out of the ordinary there either. I tried sending a ticket to snowflake support, but for some reason my account can't send support tickets in either.

Comment: When you say "anything out of the ordinary", then what is it that you are seeing?  Is the network traffic during the PUT steady through the whole 90 seconds?  Or is there high CPU for 80 seconds and then a nice spike in network traffic for the last 10 seconds?  Details would help here.

Comment: Low CPU usage the whole time. Network traffic stays at about 2.5 Mb/s (upload).

Comment: Where are you physically located in relation to the Snowflake instance that you are running on?  I'm able to get much higher throughput than that on a PUT, so your bandwidth is being restricted somewhere along the line...is my guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the number of threads by setting [PARALLEL](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/put.html#optional-parameters) to a value >1.

Comment: I have tried this. Even set it at the max 99 and there was no difference that I could see. I haven't had this issue in the past, so maybe something is going on on their end?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whatever the issue was has been resolved. I've been getting about 10-12 MB/s upload again. Not sure what the issue was, but I submitted a ticket to support a while back and it looks like they were able to fix it.

Thanks for the suggestions, but it looks like it was just something on their (or Azure's) end.